# Webmaster tool error on updated links

Tags: google-search-console

There was a page with the link http://www.xyzabc.com/exampleone . Then i updated the link as
http://www.xyzabc.com/example-one & this link is working fine now. But in webmaster tool errors still the "exampleone" link is showing 404error even i clear the error list. I made the update before 20days. still webmaster tool showing error. Can someone help us to know where we went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your site hasn't been re-indexed by Google since you've made the change. You can use "Mark as Fixed" feature in Webmaster Tools (Diagnostics/Crawl Errors), which will remove the error from the list (but it will reappear if the underlining issue remains on next reindexing).

Pretty much the only way to speed up reindexing by google bot is to use Fetch as Googlebot/Submit to Google Index feature (which is only available if your site is added/verfied in Webmaster Tools already).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We haven't tried this method til now. Will this change cause any indirect damage to the website link or content?